# Removing an observation

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This is very basic, but i have been stuck on this for a while now.

I want to **remove the observation `-Steven Sax` from Dataset `hitters.txt`**:

```
    > dput(hitters[280:290,])
structure(list(AtBat = c(439L, 453L, 528L, 633L, 16L, 562L, 281L, 
593L, 687L, 368L, 263L), Hits = c(96L, 103L, 122L, 210L, 2L, 
169L, 76L, 152L, 213L, 103L, 70L), HmRun = c(0L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 
0L, 17L, 3L, 23L, 10L, 3L, 1L), Runs = c(44L, 53L, 67L, 91L, 
1L, 88L, 42L, 69L, 91L, 48L, 26L), RBI = c(36L, 33L, 45L, 56L, 
0L, 73L, 25L, 75L, 65L, 28L, 23L), Walks = c(65L, 52L, 51L, 59L, 
0L, 53L, 20L, 53L, 27L, 54L, 30L), Years = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
2L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 4L), CAtBat = c(711L, 507L, 1716L, 3070L, 
28L, 3181L, 2658L, 2765L, 1518L, 1897L, 888L), CHits = c(148L, 
123L, 403L, 872L, 4L, 841L, 657L, 686L, 448L, 493L, 220L), CHmRun = c(1L, 
8L, 12L, 19L, 0L, 61L, 48L, 133L, 15L, 9L, 9L), CRuns = c(68L, 
63L, 211L, 420L, 1L, 450L, 324L, 369L, 196L, 207L, 83L), CRBI = c(56L, 
39L, 146L, 230L, 0L, 342L, 300L, 384L, 137L, 162L, 82L), CWalks = c(99L, 
58L, 155L, 274L, 0L, 373L, 179L, 321L, 89L, 198L, 86L), League = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "N"), class = "factor"), 
    Division = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("E", "W"), class = "factor"), PutOuts = c(229L, 
    289L, 209L, 367L, 247L, 351L, 106L, 315L, 294L, 209L, 81L
    ), Assists = c(406L, 407L, 372L, 432L, 4L, 442L, 144L, 10L, 
    445L, 246L, 147L), Errors = c(22L, 6L, 17L, 16L, 8L, 17L, 
    7L, 6L, 13L, 3L, 4L), Salary = c(150, 105, 350, 90, NA, 530, 
    341.667, 940, 350, 326.667, 250), NewLeague = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "N"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("AtBat", "Hits", "HmRun", 
"Runs", "RBI", "Walks", "Years", "CAtBat", "CHits", "CHmRun", 
"CRuns", "CRBI", "CWalks", "League", "Division", "PutOuts", "Assists", 
"Errors", "Salary", "NewLeague"), row.names = c("-Steve Jeltz", 
"-Steve Lombardozzi", "-Spike Owen", "-Steve Sax", "-Tony Armas", 
"-Tony Bernazard", "-Tom Brookens", "-Tom Brunansky", "-Tony Fernandez", 
"-Tim Flannery", "-Tom Foley"), class = "data.frame")
```

If i knew the name of the first column i would have used:

```
hitters <- hitters[!hitters$Colname == "-Steve Sax",]
```

or

```
hitters <- hitters[hitters$AtBat != "-Steve Sax", ]
```

But i don't know the name of the first column:

. I have tried: `read.table("hitters.txt", head = F)` 
`and

```
 read.table("hitters.txt", head = F)
```

My questions are:

1. How can I remove the observation?
2. Why `head = T` didnt work?

Comment: You can get the names of the columns using `names(hitters)`

Comment: You can call the first column as `hitters[,1]` if you don't know the name. Nevertheless, can you tell us the class of `hitters`object, its dimensions and print what `head(hitters)` gives you?

Comment: @Danke Don't confuse with `head` function with `header` parameter. You should put `header=T` in a first place.

Comment: @G5W thanks, but `names(hitters)` doesnt work. It gives me the names of the columns, but not of the very first one (the blue one that usually is an index number). I am not sure how to refer to the very first column (index)? In my case this "index" is the name i want to be removed - `steven sax`...

Comment: "index" = rowname ! @Dason clarified this for me.

Answer (score 1):

The first "column" represents the row names (this is not an actual column in the data set but appears as such in the output). You can access row names with the function `rownames`:

```
hitters[!rownames(hitters) %in% '-Steve Sax', ]
```

will extract the observation from the data set.

Output:

```
                  AtBat Hits HmRun Runs RBI Walks Years CAtBat CHits CHmRun CRuns
-Steve Jeltz         439   96     0   44  36    65     4    711   148      1    68
-Steve Lombardozzi   453  103     8   53  33    52     2    507   123      8    63
-Spike Owen          528  122     1   67  45    51     4   1716   403     12   211
-Tony Armas           16    2     0    1   0     0     2     28     4      0     1
-Tony Bernazard      562  169    17   88  73    53     8   3181   841     61   450
-Tom Brookens        281   76     3   42  25    20     8   2658   657     48   324
-Tom Brunansky       593  152    23   69  75    53     6   2765   686    133   369
-Tony Fernandez      687  213    10   91  65    27     4   1518   448     15   196
-Tim Flannery        368  103     3   48  28    54     8   1897   493      9   207
-Tom Foley           263   70     1   26  23    30     4    888   220      9    83
```

Comment: To clarify it's not the first column of the data - it's just the first column of the apparent output.  The rownames aren't actually columns in the dataset.

Comment: Should probably clarify in my answer. I though I might confuse the OP but mentioning it is not a column. Thanks @Dason